# Rabl needs to be specified in Gemfile that encapsulates engine that uses the gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

I am using Rabl in my engine ("Api" engine). However, the app that encapsulates the engine requires me to add `gem Rabl` in the Gemfile.

I have added rabl as a dependency in `api.gemspec`, but it does not make a difference.

The error I get if Rabl is not specified in the main app's Gemfile is:

```
Missing template api/rentable_properties/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the gemspec you're using? Make sure that it's a run_time_dependency not a development_dependency.